# Reload / insert script after inserting div via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I would like to run a script that has event listeners on a feed of posts. When I add a new post to the feed I have a function that makes a fetch call to add the post to the server and then proceed to update the DOM asynchronously. While I'm updating the DOM I would like to refresh the feed div where all the post are. I'm using an `update()` function that makes an `XMLHttpRequest` and updates the `div`, but after the new post is updated to the DOM I lose the initial script that contains event listeners for the posts.

```js
function post() {

    content = document.querySelector('#exampleFormControlTextarea1').value
    console.log(content)
    fetch('/add', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            content: content,
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        // Print result
        if (result.error) {
            document.querySelector('#message').className = "alert alert-danger rounded width_1"
            document.querySelector('#message').innerText = result.error
            document.querySelector("#message").style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.querySelector("#message").style.display = 'block';
            document.querySelector('#message').className = "alert alert-success rounded width_1"
            document.querySelector('#message').innerText = result.message
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.querySelector('#message').style.display = "none"
            }, 2500)
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.querySelector("#add").style.display = 'none';
            }, 500)
            update()
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

```js
function update() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400 && request.readyState == 4) {
            // Success!
            var resp = this.response;
            let div = document.createElement('div')
            div.innerHTML = resp
            let content = div.querySelector('#jqpost').innerHTML
            let post = document.createElement('div')
            post.innerHTML = content
            let feed = document.querySelector('#feed')
            feed.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', post)

            //console.log(script_text)
        } else {
            // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
           // console.error(request.statusText);

        }
    };
    request.open('GET', '/', true);
    request.send();

    
}
```

How can I keep the event listeners script after I reload the feed?

Comment: Put the event listeners in a function you can call each time you replace those elements. Or use event delegation

Comment: @charlietfl Can't I reload the script that handles the feed before a new post?

Comment: You could but it is not a common approach. Since you already loaded the code once making it re-usable makes most sense and is easier to troubleshoot

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your time and help @charlietfl. I'll let you know as soon as I solve the issue.